# when "B c = a" why the output isnt : "cosntructor A\n constructor B\n copy constructor B"?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

Output:

when `B c = a`  why the output isnt :

```
cosntructor A
constructor B
copy constructor B
```

instead of

```
cosntructor A
copy constructor B
```

?

========================================================================================
CODE

```
class A {

public:
    A(const A&);
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(string, int, float, int);
    B(const B&);
    B();
    ~B();
};

A::A() { cout << "constructor A\n"; }
A::A(const A& old_str) { cout << "copy constructor A\n"; }
A::~A() { cout << "destructor A\n"; }

B::B() { cout << "constructor B\n"; }
B::B(const B& old_str) { cout << "copy constructor B\n"; }
B::~B() { cout << "destructor B\n"; }

int main()
{
    B a;
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    B c = a;
    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

I don t understand when  "B c = a" for c aren t called both constructors, of A and B.  For B c the output is constructor A constructor B which is fine, why isn t the same happening for "B c = a"

Comment: Instead of delimiting each line with single quotes, add 4 space character before each line of code to form a single code block.

Comment: It would help if you explained why you expect that output. For each class instance, a single constructor is called. Since there's only one `B` created at that line, a single B constructor is called.

Comment: Only one object (`c`) is constructed in the line `B c = a;` There is no reason to expect two constructors to be called.

Comment: @j6t the `A` base-subobject of `c` is default constructed.

Comment: A question of the form _"Why the output isn't..."_ should probably include some explanation of why you believe the output should be that way.  You are making some assumption that is incorrect, but we must guess what those incorrect assumptions are.

Comment: The same *is* happening - first the `A` subobject is constructed, then the `B` part is constructed (by copying `a`). `c` is *not* first default-constructed and then copied into.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see "copy constructor A" printed because you don't copy construct the `A` base in the `B` copy constructor. You can do that in the member-initialiser-list.

```
B::B(const B& other) : A(other) { cout << "copy constructor B\n"; }
```

[See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44a1abc7598ae681)

Comment: This ANSWER is based on a false assumption. OP never asked why the "copy constructor A" is not printed. Did you misread the question? OP asked why "constructor B" is not printed.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
B c = a;
```

there is used the defined by the user the copy constructor of the class B.

```
B::B(const B& old_str) { cout << "copy constructor B\n"; }
```

The copy constructor implicitly invokes the default constructor of the base class A to create its base class sub-object. As a result you have

```
cosntructor A
copy constructor B
```

In fact the copy constructor of the class B

```
B::B(const B& old_str) { cout << "copy constructor B\n"; }
```

is equivalent to

```
B::B(const B& old_str) : A() { cout << "copy constructor B\n"; }
```

The reason of your confusing is that it seems you think that in this declaration

```
B c = a;
```

at first there is created the object `c` using the default constructor of the class `B` and then the object `a` is assigned to the created object `c` using one more constructor: the copy constructor.

However only one constructor can be used to crate an object and in this case there is used the copy constructor of the class B.

In this declaration

```
B c = a;
```

there is neither assignment. `a` is an initializer that initializers the created object `c`. You could rewrite this declaration also the following way making it more clear

```
B c( a );
```

Answer (score 0):

> when B c = a why the output isnt :

Because `B c = a;` is [**copy-initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Meaning `c` is created as a copy of object `a`, using the **copy constructor** `B::B(const B&)`. So the copy constructor `B::B(const B&)` is **implicitly called** by the compiler due to the statement `B c = a;`. Now, before entering the body of this copy constructor of `B`, the default constructor `A::A()` is also **implicitly called**. Hence you get the output:

```
constructor A
copy constructor B.
```

---

On the other hand, `B a;` is [**default initialization**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) which uses the **default constructor** `B::B()`. So the default constructor `B::B()` is **implicitly called** due to the statement `B a;`. But before entering the body of this default constructor of `B`, the default constructor `A::A()` is also **implicitly called**. Hence you get the output:

```
constructor A
constructor B
```